# Write to CSV file after re.sub Python

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

I have done a regex substitution on a CSV file that prints following output, just like anything else:

```
H1,H2,H3
A1,GG,98
B3,KLK,Oe
```

But when I write it to a CSV file, it writes complete line in one cell (doesn't use commas as delimiters even though specified). I used the `writer.writerow(row.split("\n"))` to write, where row is the data obtained after re.sub (i.e. the output posted above).

Comment: To clarify: `row` is a string containing the output you posted (`H1,H2,H3\nA1,...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

```
A row must be a sequence of strings or numbers
```

You are passing a list of *rows*, not individual values. You have to split each row by commas:

```
for row in row.split('\n'):
    writer.writerow(row.split(','))
```